# How can I display a dialog above the keyboard

Tags: android

I'm a newbie with android, I write an application which using the Dialog to display data when user select on one thing. This is how the dialog looks:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3NUAgD0tB0YOS16azFCWXdSVVE/edit

But when I tap on the last EditText to enter some data, the dialog still shows, when I type the first character, the dialog scrolls down. The dialog stays behind the keyboard, with some parts totally obscured.

Could anyone tell me how to show the whole dialog above the soft keyboard? This is how I'd like it to look:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3NUAgD0tB0YOFVQYUF0U0JvOEk/edit

Thanks

Clark

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may need to set dialog's width and height manually in order to make soft input mode work like this:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    window.setAttributes(params); 
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE );
```

Comment: The last line of this code is completely incorrect! 
From the android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN) for `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN`:
This **can not** be combined with `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE`;

Comment: It seems that you are right. I didn't checked the documentation before and internet is full of examples like i write here. I am fixing my answer now. Thank you for urging me.

Comment: If i use edittext with alertdialog then it can possible to open softkeybord over the dialog in other application?

Answer (score 30):

Have you tried ths one?

Worked for me:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSoftInputMode(int).

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: Thank you, Waza_Be

It works great. This is what i want. I can display the dialog above the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

create a Xml file name **style.xml**

```
<style name="FullHeightDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnchanged</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dialog_transparent</item>
</style>
```

then Implement

this works for me hoping it will work for you also.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this , R.style.FullHeightDialog);
```

and also do changes in your manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Comment: `adjustPan` can't be combined with `adjustResize`. It's explicitly stated in docs

Comment: Actually adjustPan|adjustResize = adjustNothing

Answer (score 1):

```
 AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
 dialog.show();
 Window window = dialog.getWindow();
 window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
 window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I dont want to use AlertDialog because I need to controll how the keyboard pops up for edit text properly.